# Pass value from inside method to another class

Tags: c#, string, methods, pass-by-reference

I am trying to pass the value "test" from within the class WorkspaceNoteUpdateComponent and within the method noteUpdateControl_AddNoteClicked, over to another class NoteUpdateUserControl and method buttonAdd_Click. For some reason however, it appears that the value of "test" within the first method never makes it out to be passed along. What am I doing wrong?

Class WorkspaceNoteUpdateComponent with method noteUpdateControl_AddNoteClicked

```
public class WorkspaceNoteUpdateComponent : IWorkspaceComponent2
{
    private IRecordContext _recContext;
    public static string CustAddrCity = "SOMETHING";


    public Control GetControl()
    {
        NoteUpdateUserControl noteUpdateControl = new NoteUpdateUserControl();
        noteUpdateControl.AddNoteClicked += new NoteUpdateUserControl.AddNoteHandler(noteUpdateControl_AddNoteClicked);

        return noteUpdateControl;
    }

    public string noteUpdateControl_AddNoteClicked(ref string CustAddrCity)
    {
        IContact contactRecord = _recContext.GetWorkspaceRecord(RightNow.AddIns.Common.WorkspaceRecordType.Contact) as IContact;

        CustAddrCity = "test";

        _recContext.RefreshWorkspace();
        return CustAddrCity;
    }
}
```

Class NoteUpdateUserControl with method buttonAdd_Click

```
public partial class NoteUpdateUserControl : UserControl
{
    public delegate string AddNoteHandler(ref string custAddrCity);
    public event AddNoteHandler AddNoteClicked;
    string _boxtext = WorkspaceNoteUpdateComponent.CustAddrCity;

    public NoteUpdateUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (AddNoteClicked != null)
        {


            MessageBox.Show(_boxtext);
        }
    }
```

***UPDATE removed readonly from string _boxtext as this wasn't an intended part of the code****

Comment: `_boxtext` in your user control is not a reference to the `CustAddrCity` in the Workspace class, its a copy of it. You marked it as readonly and only initialize it on the construction of the object, somehow you need to physically update that value.

Comment: Also, this is an unfortunate side effect of (mis)-using variable names. `CustAddrCity` inside the method is not the same as `CustAddrCity` outside of the method, the compiler assumes you want the local copy inside the method, and it is not setting the one in the class. I think you may want to read up on what `static`, `readonly` and `ref` do.

Comment: Ron, thanks for the input, I have updated my post as the readonly part was not intended. That was actually a mistake. I realize my mistake with the static part in the declaration of CustAddrCity.

Answer (score 0):

Are you triggering your event in any other place?

Your code is missing the event triggering:

```
    if (AddNoteClicked != null)
    {
        string _eventBoxText = _boxtext;

        AddNoteClicked(ref _eventBoxText);  //<-- YOU NEED THIS LINE TO TRIGGER YOUR EVENT

        MessageBox.Show(_eventBoxText );
    }
```

Note I replaced `_boxtext` by `_eventBoxText`, `_boxtext` is readonly and thus [would not be acceptable as `ref` argument in any context other method than the class constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/acdd6hb7.aspx).